# How do I sort items in my listbox in ascending order

Tags: c#, sorting, listbox

I have a listbox that is populated with the code below, but I wish to sort the items in it. How do I sort the items in the listbox

```
public void refreshInterface()
{
    foreach (DataSet1.xspGetAnalysisUsageTypesRow homeForms in myDataSet.xspGetAnalysisUsageTypes)
    {
        var forms = new FormItems(homeForms);
        listBox1.Items.Add(forms);
    }
}
```

FormItems Class:

```
public class FormItems
{
    public DataSet1.xspGetAnalysisUsageTypesRow types { get; set; }

    public FormItems(DataSet1.xspGetAnalysisUsageTypesRow usageTypes)
    {
        types = usageTypes;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.types.xlib_Desc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either update the source items or the items directly on the listbox by using LINQ:

```
list.OrderBy(x => x.Property)
```

Where you can set x.Property to the property you want to sort by. That sort will default to ascending which is what you want. Otherwise just use `OrderByDescending()`

Comment: for Linq, you need to add using System.Linq, I often used to forget that when I was learning Linq...

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for sorting LisBox items A->Z or Z->A :

```
public void Sorting(ListBox lst, String order) {
                 if (order.Equals("A-Z"))
                {
                    if (lst.Items.Count > 1)
                    {
                        bool swapped;
                        do
                        {
                            int counter = lst.Items.Count - 1;
                            swapped = false;

                            while (counter > 0)
                            {
                                // Compare the items 
                                if (lst.Items[counter].ToString().CompareTo(lst.Items[counter -
    1].ToString()) < 0)
                                {
                                    // Swap the items.
                                    object temp = lst.Items[counter];
                                    lst.Items[counter] = lst.Items[counter - 1];
                                    lst.Items[counter - 1] = temp;
                                    swapped = true;
                                }
                                // Decrement the counter.
                                counter -= 1;
                            }
                        }
                        while ((swapped == true));
                    }
                }
                if (order.Equals("Z-A")) {
                    if (lst.Items.Count > 1)
                    {
                        bool swapped;
                        do
                        {
                            int counter = lst.Items.Count - 1;
                            swapped = false;

                            while (counter > 0)
                            {
                                // Compare the items 
                                if (lst.Items[counter].ToString().CompareTo(lst.Items[counter -
    1].ToString()) > 0)
                                {
                                    // Swap the items.
                                    object temp = lst.Items[counter];
                                    lst.Items[counter] = lst.Items[counter - 1];
                                    lst.Items[counter - 1] = temp;
                                    swapped = true;
                                }
                                // Decrement the counter.
                                counter -= 1;
                            }
                        }
                        while ((swapped == true));
                    }
                }

            }
```